# Extract the last 2 digits of an integer (Java)

Tags: java, integer, double, println

I have some code that takes an integer and extracts the last 2 numbers and prints them. For example, if I input 10000001, 01 should be the printout/ output. The problem here is that for some reason the output of the program is 1. I am not sure why the output shows up as a single digit.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double num = 10000001;
    double digit = num % 100;
    System.out.println(digit);    
  }
}
```

Comment: 1 is the correct answer. If you want leading zeros you will have to arrange the appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple and has a simple answer.
In java `int num = 1;` is same as `int num = 01;` (both mean same `1` for the compiler) so when you are using `% 100` with your number it returns `01` which is nothing but `1` for java as you are storing it to a double data type variable (actually when you use double in this line `double digit = num % 100;` it prints 1.0 , so you should use int here `int digit = num % 100;`  to remove the decimal point).
So using `int digit = num % 100;` will work and give you desired results with all number except numbers having a `0` before a number.

To solve your problem completely you can use String class.

```
String str = num+""; //connverting int to string
String digit = str.substring(str.length()-2, str.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your calculated value is "01". which while display java is considering it as "1". You can use padding but have to convert that integer to a string.

```
public static void main(String []args){
  double num = 10000001;
  int digit =(int) num%100;
  String padding =String.format("%02d",digit);
  System.out.println(padding);
}
```

**Or** If you are taking binary numbers better to use string and then displaying last two numbers using length() on string.

Answer (score 0):

Another method you can try out is extracting the last two digits and printing as string.

```
int num = 10001;
int last_digit = num % 10; // extract the last digit
num /= 10; // modify the original number
int second_to_last_digit = num % 10; // extract second last digit
String str = String.valueOf(second_to_last_digit) + String.valueOf(last_digit); // convert and add strings
System.out.println(str); // print desired string
```